# How to center vertically text in figure?

Tags: html, css, text, centering

I would like to have both texts center vertically to image on resolution 720px.
The text "serwis" is not centered vertically to image right now.
How should I do it?
Here's a demo [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mOWMrm)

HTML code

```
<section class="primary">
        <figure class="primary__figure">
            <img class="primary__img" src="http://www.linkpad.me/static/img/welcome/key.png" alt="">
            <figcaption class="primary__caption">serwis</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure class="primary__figure">
            <img class="primary__img" src="http://www.linkpad.me/static/img/welcome/key.png" alt="">
            <figcaption class="primary__caption primary__caption--secondary">częsci zamienne</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </section>
```

SCSS code

```
$font: 'Lato', sans-serif;
$break-medium: 45em;
@function calculateRem($size) {
    $remSize: $size / 16px;
    @return $remSize * 1rem;
}
@mixin font-size($size) {
    font-size: $size;
    font-size: calculateRem($size);
}
.primary {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(10,198,162) 0%,rgb(0,160,175) 100%);
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    @media only screen and (min-width: $break-medium) {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    &__figure {
        padding: 20px;
    }

    &__img {
        width: 100px;
    }

    &__caption {
        font-family: $font;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 700;
        @include font-size(30px);
        text-align: center;
        color: rgb(255,255,255);
        padding-top: 10px;
        @media only screen and (min-width: $break-medium) {
            float: right;
            @include font-size(40px);
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

        &--secondary {
            width: 100px;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            @media only screen and (min-width: $break-medium)               {
                width: 200px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make a snippet?

Comment: Here it is http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mOWMrm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `float: right` in `<figcaption>`. Floated elements cannot be used for `vertical-align`. So, you need to do:

```
.primary__caption, .primary__img {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbpvyL**

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Praveen Kumar answer, you can also use

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

And of course the parent needs to have

```
display:table;
```